# Null-conditional operator analog in .NET 3.5 / 4.0, VS 2012 / 2013?

Tags: c#, linq, nullable, null-conditional-operator

In my code I have to access values calling several property getters:

```
IFoo1 a = objA.Prop1.Value;
IFoo2 b = objB.Prop2.Prop3.Value;
IFoo3 c = objC.Prop4.Prop5.Prop6.Value;
```

Every property can be null. So to access every value I must use nested if-blocks:

```
IFoo2 b = null;

if(objB.Prop2!=null)
{
    if(objB.Prop2.Prop3!=null)
    {
         b = objB.Prop2.Prop3.Value;
    }
}
```

How can I improve this code to reduce amount of if-blocks? Can I use any lambda expressions, LINQ, IExpression, etc, to somehow replace it with:

IFoo2 b = GetVal(objB.Prop2.Prop3.Value);

All PropX are of different types and I have hundreds of such properties.
I must use .NET 3.5 or at least .NET 4.0. I can not use any later versions.

*IMPORTANT EDIT:*

**I must also use Visual Studio 2012 and 2013. I can not target VS 2015.**

Comment: Please see the Student class here: http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/the-null-conditional-operator, I have the same issue.

Comment: Which version of VS do you use? If it's VS2015, you can use the C# 6 null-conditional operator, even when targeting .NET 3.5 or 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it, but it's very very quick and dirty. Some obvious flaws:

1. For the expression a.b.c - we invoke 'a', then 'a.b', then 'a.b.c', checking for null each time. We should store the return of the previous invocation, and modify the member expression to operate on our result. Only really an issue if the member access is expensive, otherwise it's equivalent to `if (a != null && a.b != null && a.b.c != null) return a.b.c.d;` which is a fairly common pattern
2. It only works for member expressions

```
public static T GetOrNull<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression) 
    where T : class
{

    var memberExpressions = new List<MemberExpression>();
    var membExpress = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
    while (membExpress != null)
    {
        memberExpressions.Add(membExpress);
        membExpress = membExpress.Expression as MemberExpression;
    }
    memberExpressions.Skip(1).Reverse();

    foreach(var membExpr in memberExpressions.Skip(1).Reverse()) {
        var lambdaExpr = Expression.Lambda(membExpr);
        var currentRes = lambdaExpr.Compile().DynamicInvoke();
        if (currentRes == null)
            return null;
    }   

    return (T)Expression.Lambda(expression.Body).Compile().DynamicInvoke();
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var tmp = new classA();

var res = GetOrNull(() => tmp.Prop1.Prop2);
res.Dump(); //Gives null

tmp.Prop1 = new classA.classB();
tmp.Prop1.Prop2 = new classA.classB.classC();
res = GetOrNull(() => tmp.Prop1.Prop2);
res.Dump(); //returns object of type `classC`
```

Comment: You're compiling dynamic methods at runtime and then invoking them with reflection without any kind of caching. It's a nice solution, but should be used very cautiously. Performance impact would be in the area of 10,000x slower or more.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you need C# 6 to use the null-conditional operator (`?.`).

However, you can simulate it with extension methods like these:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static TReturn NCR<T, TReturn>(this T instance, Func<T, TReturn> getter)
        where T : class
        where TReturn : class
    {
        if (instance != null)
            return getter(instance);
        return null;
    }

    public static TReturn NCR<T, TReturn>(this T? instance, Func<T, TReturn> getter)
        where T : struct
        where TReturn : class
    {
        if (instance != null)
            return getter(instance.Value);
        return null;
    }

    public static TReturn? NCV<T, TReturn>(this T instance, Func<T, TReturn> getter)
        where T : class
        where TReturn : struct
    {
        if (instance != null)
            return getter(instance);
        return null;
    }

    public static TReturn? NCV<T, TReturn>(this T? instance, Func<T, TReturn> getter)
    where T : struct
    where TReturn : struct
    {
        if (instance != null)
            return getter(instance.Value);
        return null;
    }
}
```

(NC stands for Null-Conditional, R stands for Reference type, V stands for Value type; it's ugly, but unfortunately C# doesn't allow method overloads that differ only by the generic constraints)

You can use them like this:

```
IFoo3 c = objC.NCR(_ => _.Prop4)
              .NCR(_ => _.Prop5)
              .NCR(_ => _.Prop6)
              .NCR(_ => _.Value);
```

(use NCV instead of NCR if the property to get returns a value type)

It's still too verbose, but at least it's easier to see what the code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Best you can probably do is using a compound `if` condition like

```
IFoo2 b = null;

if(objB.Prop2 != null && objB.Prop2.Prop3 != null)
{ 
  b = objB.Prop2.Prop3.Value;
}
```

(OR) using a `Ternary Operator` like

```
IFoo2 b = (objB.Prop2 != null && objB.Prop2.Prop3 != null) ? objB.Prop2.Prop3.Value : null;
```

Answer (score -1):

.NET 4.6 now has a ?. operator that solves this exact problem.

http://www.volatileread.com/Wiki?id=2104

This allows you to write it like this.

IFoo3 c = objC?.Prop4?.Prop5?.Prop6?.Value;

You might get around this by creating a helper function, but the clarity and simplicity of the code won't get anywhere near this. If possible, upgrade to get that feature.

Comment: I have to use .NET 3.5 or .NET 4.0.

Comment: The new operator is tied to the C# compiler, not .NET. (It basically emits all the error-checking code that one would normally do 'by hand'.)

Comment: It doesn't matter which .NET version you use, as long as you use the C# 6 compiler

Comment: Its not .net 4.6, its c# 6.0, as its a compoler feature nit CLR.

Comment: Any chance to simulate Null-conditional operator in VS 2012 or at least 2013?

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks! Which means you can simply upgrade to Visual Studio 2015 and still use .NET 3.5 :) I'll start putting that to use myself! Plus you can get Visual Studio 2015 for free. Although I also understand that in some business environments, you're not the one to decide the tools you're working with. In that case you have to convince the manager to make the switch. Or is there any reason you don't want to upgrade? The Community edition may be enough for your needs.
https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs

Comment: I downvoted because the entire purpose of this question is to find a substitute for the very feature you tell us to use; this answer adds no value. The asker *specifically* states: "**I must also use Visual Studio 2012 and 2013. I can not target VS 2015**."